When I call stream() where is the inner Iterator or inner Spliterator?
The classes implementing the collection interface have the stream() method, and I see that it returns the stream interface when the stream() method is called. I know there will be some internal implementations, and you can just use the stream interface method. But I'm curious. Where is the inner iteration? Collection Implementation?? or Stream Implementation?? I don't think this is the way to borrow the result of calling the splitter() method when it's needed to be repeated...
Am I asking a weird question? I just wonder where the instance exists in memory.. There's no way to find out even if I search this for 3 days, and I don't know how to observe Java memory..
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Spliterator;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class StreamDebugTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add("A");
        list.add("B");
        list.add("C");

        Stream<String> stream = list.stream();
        
        stream.map(s -> {
                System.out.println("Changing: " + s);
                return s.toLowerCase();
            })
            .forEach(s -> {
                System.out.println("last: " + s);
            });
            
        Stream<String> newStream = list.stream();
        Spliterator<String> spliterator = newStream.spliterator();
    }
}


//================
All the brilliant terms you haven't seen in java tutorials are killing me. Is there a way to learn more about this?? Reference Pipeline was not even seen in java8 Oracle Docs...

Of course, the documentation does not mention the names of internal implementation classes. But it’s not clear what you are actually searching for.

@Holger In conclusion, I was wondering by which class the "internal iterator" was implemented. I saw content related to internal iterators in the Java tutorial book, and after that, I was curious about this, so I referred to the Java document, but I became even more mysterious. After that, I tried to look at the debugging tool and search it, but it was too difficult to know where to start.

Later, I found out that Reference Pipeline was a thing I didn't know. thank @dani-vita. I think that reached the point where concrete implementations determine the behavior of iterators through intermediate and final operations.
The external iterator is to get and manipulate the iterator.
I understand that the classes of iterator are the same, but there seems to be a conceptual difference. The internal iterator is determining only the operation in advance in the functional interface of the wrapped Stream interface and obtaining the final repetition result. So far...

The main problem of the debugging state shown in your screenshot is that it has been taken after the stream operation has been performed. Therefore, you see sourceSpliterator = null. When you look into the state before the forEach call, you’d see the actual internal iterator right there. It’s equivalent to an iterator acquired via list.spliterator() (and also newStream.spliterator() as long as you didn’t chain intermediate operations).

You can also set a breakpoint at the System.out.println("last: " + s); statement, to see how the Stream calls into the internal iterator which then calls into the actual per-element operation which ends up at your action. However, there’s a lot of distracting noise in the reference implementation making it harder to identify the relevant parts.

@Holger Thank you for your feedback on setting breakpoints and guiding me on where to observe. I confirmed during runtime that the iterator is iterating as expected and that it is not null. Thank you.

If you take a look at the implementation of the Collection.stream() method, you would see that this invokes the StreamSupport.stream() method, which creates a new instance of the concrete static nested class ReferencePipeline.Head. The two classes ReferencePipeline and ReferencePipeline.Head basically provide your stream implementation.
In fact, when you ask about the implementation of the collection iteration, or a better phrasing: the iteration of the stream elements, this is handled by the ReferencePipeline class. This abstract class contains the implementation of all stream operations (forEach(), count(), etc.).
For example, the forEach() operation iterates non-parallel streams via the Spliterator.forEachRemaining() method. The count() operation relies on the evaluateSequential() or evaluateParallel() to compute the value via a Spliterator. As you can see, under the hood, the iteration actually happens in terminal operations via iterators. This is because streams are lazily evaluated, and unless their operations aren't used by a terminal operation, these are not executed at all.
Taking on from @Slaw's comment, I've decided to include a debug example of the count() terminal operation. Supposing that we have the following line of code List.of(1,2,3).stream().count();.

When we step into count(), we can see that the ReferencePipeline.count() method is invoked.

Inside this method, it is made a call to AbstractPipeline.evaluate() by passing an implementation of the TerminalOp interface returned from the ReduceOps.makeRefCounting() method (this argument passage is important for later).

Once inside evaluate(), since the stream is not parallel, the method invokes evaluateSequential() from a TerminalOp instance.

The instance in question is an anonymous implementation of the ReduceOp abstract class. Specifically, the exact instance returned by ReduceOps.makeRefCounting() at step 2.

At this point, we can see that the evaluateSequential() being executed is the one defined in the anonymous ReduceOp definition made in the ReduceOps.makeRefCounting() method.

Inside of evaluateSequential(), it is made an invocation to the PipelineHelper.exactOutputSizeIfKnown() method, whose definition is the one inherited from AbstractPipeline.exactOutputSizeIfKnown().

Lastly, once we step into AbstractPipeline.exactOutputSizeIfKnown(), we can see that the size is computed from the getExactSizeIfKnown() method of the given Spliterator instance.



By combining the JDK GitHub and the Oracle Java documentation, I was able to infer the internal workings. Thank you for showing me the method; my curiosity has been resolved.
